# Converting SQL Server string to datetime for import into Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, import, toad

I am using automation designer in TOAD to import data from SQL Server via an odbc connection into an Oracle table.

One of the columns is a string `ssdatetimestr` of the form `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.mmmmm`. I want to use an expression in the import wizard to convert this to an Oracle date.

I have tried the expression

```
to_date(substr(ssdatetimestr,1,19),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

but this throws an error

> 'to_date' is not a valid date and time

Any suggestions

Comment: So you're truncating the milliseconds portion of the date? Can you share the string/data you're running the conversion against?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [`DATE`/`TIMESTAMP`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) literals:

> To specify a DATE value as a literal, you must use the Gregorian calendar. You can specify an ANSI literal, as shown in this example:
>
> ```
> DATE '1998-12-25'
> ```
>
> ---
>
> The TIMESTAMP datatype stores year, month, day, hour, minute, and second, and fractional second values. When you specify TIMESTAMP as a literal, the fractional_seconds_precision value can be any number of digits up to 9, as follows:
>
> ```
> TIMESTAMP '1997-01-31 09:26:50.124'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you gave (it would have been better if you had included the ORA-nnnn number) suggests the problem is not in the construction of the to_date function (I see nothing wrong with it, BTW) but rather how it was used in context.  But you don't give us the context ... the full statement that included your to_date